# Gulp4 watch не реагирует на изменения

Tags: gulp-watch, webpack4, gulp4

Должно реагировать на изменения в файлах стиля, но даже на js нет реакции!

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
// import {get as browserSync} from 'browser-sync';
import watch from 'gulp-watch';

// const bs = browserSync('server');


var bSync = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    bSync.init({
        server: { baseDir: "../" },
        notify: true
    });
});


gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browser-sync', ()=> {
    global.watch = true;

    gulp.watch('app/{styles,blocks}/**/*.+(less|styl)', gulp.series('styles', 'styles:lint', bSync.reload('styles/app-min.css')));
    gulp.watch(['app/+(images|fonts)/**/*', 'app/*.html'], gulp.parallel('copy', bSync.reload)); // или watch( вместо gulp.watch(

    gulp.start('scripts:watch');
    bSync.reload();
}));
```

а вот для скриптов:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import errorHandler from 'gulp-plumber-error-handler';
import makeWebpackConfig from '../webpack.conf.js';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const {NODE_ENV, NOTIFY} = process.env;
const isDebug = NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const scriptsErrorHandler = errorHandler('Error in \'scripts\' task');

function runWebpack(watch = false) {
    return function (callback) {
        const webpackConfig = makeWebpackConfig({
            watch,
            debug: isDebug,
            sourcemaps: isDebug,
            notify: NOTIFY
        });

        return webpack(webpackConfig, (error, stats) => {
            const jsonStats = stats.toJson();
            if (jsonStats.errors.length) {
                jsonStats.errors.forEach(message => {
                    scriptsErrorHandler.call({emit() {}}, {message});
                });
            }

            if (watch === false) callback();
        });
    };
}

gulp.task('watch', runWebpack(false));    
gulp.task('scripts:watch', runWebpack(true));
```

Задания находятся в папке tasks и для их загрузке, в задании default используется модуль gulp-hub:

```
var HubRegistry = require('gulp-hub');
gulp.registry(new HubRegistry(['*.js']));
```

В чем проблема?